# Creating a dataframe from a dictionary column in CSV with multiple columns

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new here and just started to learn python (jupyter nb).

I have a csv file with multiple columns. One of the column is list of dictionaries (string based).
I'd like to explode the list of dictionaries into rows, while still having the rest of the data similar to the parent's row, and would like to put into a dataframe

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hi | 20 | [{"a": 1, "b": 2},{"c": 3, "d": 4}] |

What I had done is to use evaluate function to make the list of dictionaries readable, then use the iteration function to put into new empty list and then converted it into dataframe, which resulting in table as below
| a | b | c | d |
|:---- |:------:| :-----:| -----:|
| hi  | 20    | a | 1|
| | | b | 2|
| | | c | 3|
| | | d | 4|

Is there a way to make it as such?

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hi | 20 | a | 1 |
| hi | 20 | b | 2 |
| hi | 20 | c | 3 |
| hi | 20 | d | 4 |

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming thar `b4.csv` is your input CSV file:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'b4.csv',
    converters={
        'c': lambda x: [list(d.items()) for d in eval(x)]
    },
    delimiter=';'
)

df = df.explode('c').explode('c')
df['d'] = df.c.map(lambda x: x[1])
df['c'] = df.c.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Here the resulting DataFrame:

```sh
    a   b  c  d
0  hi  20  a  1
0  hi  20  b  2
0  hi  20  c  3
0  hi  20  d  4
```

Comment: Nice one! I have never used the `converters` option. Would be interesting to investigate how it compares performance wise to my solution. (The remaining steps look somewhat similar.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'c': {0: [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]}, 'a': {0: 'hi'}, 'b': {0: 20}})
exploded = df.c.explode().apply(lambda d: d.items()).explode().apply(pd.Series)
```

This first converts the list to a series. Second, converts the dictionaries to a list of tuples. Third, explodes the list of tuples. Finally, converts this to a list to form a `DataFrame`.

You can then perform simple transformations to get the desired result:

```
exploded.columns = ['c', 'd']
exploded[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']]
exploded.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)  # ensure resulting index is valid
```